# A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7.1:site: org/apache/maven/reporting/AbstractMavenReport

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

I try to use `mvn site` to create site for my maven project, but I get the following Error. I have try to delete `maven-site-plugin/` and `/org/apache/maven/reporting` from my .m2/repository, but it doesn't work. Is there any know how to solve this problem?

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7.1:site (default-site) on project tutorial: Execution default-site of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7.1:site failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7.1:site: org/apache/maven/reporting/AbstractMavenReport
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/yangguanrong/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.7.1/maven-site-plugin-3.7.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/yangguanrong/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-exec/1.4/maven-reporting-exec-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/Users/yangguanrong/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/3.0/maven-reporting-api-3.0.jar
...
```

Part of my pom.xml is shown following:

```xml
<build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
        <plugins>
            <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Because `org/apache/maven/reporting/AbstractMavenReport` is a class of `maven-reporting-impl`, I try to add `maven-reporting-impl` as a dependency. However, it still doesn't work.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.reporting/maven-reporting-impl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.reporting</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-reporting-impl</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```